# How to make my standalone game not require blender installation?

Tags: game-engine

I am making a game and I want it to not require Blender to be installed in order to play it. Currently it needs 'blenderplayer.app'.

I am using Linux Ubuntu 14.10, Blender 2.72b. How can I do this?

Comment: Do you want to make a standalone executable?

Comment: Yes, and so it does not requiere blender to be installed(Save as Runtime Game uses blenderplayer as engine).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the "Game Engine: Save as Game Engine Runtime" add-on:

[image: Add-on selection]

Then you can save the game as executable, which can be run without needing to install Blender:

[image: Saving the game]

You will end up with an executable, and a directory named after the Blender version. The executable will be for the same OS as you performed these actions on.

Comment: I use it already, but I think so other users need Blenderplayer.app so they can play this...

Comment: Something.app looks like a MacOS application, yet you are using Linux. Please provide us with facts that show the suggested answer doesn't work, as we need that to provide a proper solution.

Comment: Sorry, but it appears so it is working on other devices without Blender. So runtime game is enaught. Marking as answered.

Answer (score -1):

The blend file only contains data, you need to use either blender or blenderplayer to view that data and play your game.

blenderplayer is a "view only" application, it is blender without the ability to edit the data. When you distribute your game other people will need to use blenderplayer to play the game, you can either include the player with your data files or tell people to download it themselves.

If you don't want to include blenderplayer then you will need to export your data to a different file format and create another application for your game. Only your model data will transfer so any game logic will need to be re-done.

[Unity](http://unity3d.com/) is a popular game creation application. [Godot Engine](http://www.godotengine.org/) is a newer opensource option. [gamekit](https://code.google.com/p/gamekit/) is another option if you want to program your game from scratch.