# Is it possible to export a multiplayer game from BGE?

Tags: game-engine, export

It is extremely simple to export a single player game, but I have not been able to find a way to create/export a multiplayer game from the  BGE.

Is this theoretically possible *without* using a third party application?

Comment: What type of multiplayer are you talking about? Two or more users playing split screen on one computer, or connected over a network.

Comment: For use over network or hosted on the internet. I would like to do this without external applications if possible . . .

Comment: Why is this suggested for closing because it is `too broad`? This is very specific. Is this specific thing (exporting multiplayer games) possible with Blender?

Comment: How is this different from exporting a single-player game like explained in [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21320/how-to-make-my-standalone-game-not-require-blender-installation/21335#21335)?

Comment: That doesn't explain how to export a *multiplayer* game. I am fully aware of how to create a normal single player game :-P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:**  No, at least not without a lot of effort.

**Long answer:**

The engine has no baked-in network multiplayer.  You have to set up the whole thing yourself with Python scripting.  It's all quite complex.

As far as I know this is the most in-depth explanation of the subject:
http://youtu.be/4xZRfzOtxzA

^ Should you decide to build that into a full game, be sure to swap pickle for something like json.  Using pickle on untrusted data is a *nightmarish fiery hell of insecurity*.

If you're familiar with Python and compiling, check out the Python bindings for ENet:
https://github.com/aresch/pyenet

At one point someone was working on an addon to ease the burden for common folk, but last I checked it wasn't matured enough for actual use.  The project *might* be dead as well:
http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?242740-Blender-Game-Engine-Multiplayer-Add-on

Comment: I was afraid that would be the case. Thanks for answering!